# How do I mock an overloaded function with const/non

Tags: c++, googlemock

How do I mock the following code?

```
class ISomeClass
{
public:
   virtual ~ISomeClass() {} = 0;
   virtual const MyType & getType() const = 0;
   virtual MyType & getType() = 0;
};
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn´t work. Can you please help me?

```
class MockSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
public:
    using MyTypeConstRefType = const MyType&;
    using MyTypeRefType = MyType&;

public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(getType, MyTypeConstRefType(void) const);

    MOCK_METHOD0(getType, MyTypeRefType(void));
};
```

Comment: [`MOCK_CONST_METHOD`](https://github.com/google/googlemock/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mock_const_method)

Comment: Thank you! I don´t know why I couldn´t find any information regarding this.

Comment: Yeah, I got very confused by this the first time. In the end, someone else on my team had already used it in a different file, and I spotted it there. No idea how they found out about it in the first place.

Comment: @BobTFish If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They provide a separate set of macros for `const` member functions ("methods"): [`MOCK_CONST_METHOD#`](https://github.com/google/googletest/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MOCK_CONST_METHOD). So in your case, it would be:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(getType, MyTypeConstRefType());
```

The usage is otherwise identical to `MOCK_METHOD#`, taking the function name in the first argument and function type in the second.